# iOS MPMoviePlayer triggers random action after leaving fullscreen

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a wired issue where my MPMoviePlayer triggers, at least it seems like, an action when leaving fullscreen. Actually it repeats the animation that happened before. I recorded it because it is hard to explain, here is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNzRItQhD8M

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this certainly can only be a guess, I still am rather convinced that your problem is a pretty common pitfall of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

I would be looking very closely at your `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` implementations.

Remember that those are invoked whenever a view is getting visible and that happens also when the fullscreen playback is ending / switched back to embedded mode as that reveals your views (again).

Make sure that any animations actions you are triggering within these methods are only triggered when needed.

A very well suited signal would be the `fullscreen` property of `MPMoviePlayerController`. Within your appearance callbacks, check if that propery is set to `YES` and if so, do not start the unwanted actions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed is the issue. I would never have thought of that. Now i am not sure how to solve it because when the player leaves fullscreen, its fullscreen property is set to NO. I need a way to know that the player is coming from fullscreen. Any idea?

Comment: I solved it by using the viewDidLoad for the animation instead of viewDiDAppear. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @drale2k you should be careful when using viewDidLoad for triggering animations. I would recommend against doing so and propose to subscribe to the MPMoviePlayerWill/DidEnter fullscreen notifications. Within those handlers you could set a flag signalling that your player just came from fullscreen - which could in turn then be used as a signal within your viewWill/DidAppear implementations. Ow, and btw my fault in being a little vague; you should be able to get a `fullscreen == YES` in your viewWillAppear (but not in viewDidAppear).

Comment: Heh that is exactly what i tried to do but for whatever reason the 2 notifications did not fire and i tried it in viewDidLoad. I will try it later again. now i happy that i "solved" it in the worst case :)

Btw fullscreen is still NO in viewWillAppear. I think it is only YES if it actually is in fullscreen, not while leaving.